# Closed orientable 2-manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ closed orientable 2-manifold and $\chi (M) = 2$.
Why is $M$ a sphere?

I want a prove with triangulation.

Comment: The Euler characteristic is related to the genus by $\chi(M) = 2-2g$. This implies $g=0$.

Comment: @Nick your answer has one mistake. definition of genus is $ g := \frac{- \chi (M) + 2}{2}$ and your answer has cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By classification of surfaces, two closed orientable surfaces are homeomorphic if and only if their Euler characteristics agree. To show that $\chi(S^2) = 2$, consider a vertex with a loop to itself (1 edge), then glue two discs (2 faces) with disjoint interiors along the loop.